# Combine data from csv files

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have 100 csv files with the same number of columns (different number of rows) in the following pattern:

Files 1:

```
A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
A3,B3,C3
A4,B4,C4
```

File 2:

```
*A1*,*B1*,*C1*
*A2*,*B2*,*C2*
*A3*,*B3*,*C3*
```

File ...

Output:

```
A1+*A1*+...,B1+*B1*+...,C1+*C1*+...
A2+*A2*+...,B2+*B2*+...,C2+*C2*+...
A3+*A3*+...,B3+*B3*+...,C3+*C3*+...
A4+...     ,B4+...     ,C4+...
```

For example:

Files 1:

```
1,0,0
1,0,1
1,0,0
0,1,0
```

Files 2:

```
1,1,0
1,1,1
0,1,0
```

Output:

```
2,1,0
2,1,2
1,1,0
0,1,0
```

I am really breaking my head on how to solve this... Could any body give me some advise?

Thanks a lot and best regards,
Julian

Edit:
I want to thank 'pepr' a lot for his very elaborated answer but I would like to find a solution using pandas as suggested by 'furas'.
I have found a way to create the variables for all my files like this:

```
dic={}
for i in range(14253,14352):
        try:
                dic['df_{0}'.format(i)]=pandas.read_csv('output_'+str(i)+'.csv')
        except:
                pass
```

but if I try the suggested

```
df1['column_A'] += df2['column_*A*']
```

Because I have 100 files in my case it would have to be something like

```
for residue in residues:
       for number in range(14254,14255):
               df=dic['df_14253'][residue]
               df+=dic['df_'+str(number)][residue]
```

I have the problem that my files have different numbers of rows and are only summed up until the last row of df1. How could I solve this? I think groupby.sum by panda could be an option but I don't understand how to use it.

PS: residues is a list which contains all the column headers.

Comment: I don't know how to start... I was thinking that maybe I could handle it as a matrix and then use some numpy library. To read each file line by line and then adding the data seems too complicated / unpythonish for me... I was hoping that the csv module would have a funcion for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with standard modules can be like this:

```
#!python3

import csv
import itertools

fname1 = 'file1.csv'
fname2 = 'file2.csv'
fname_out = 'output.csv'
with open(fname1, newline='') as f1,\
     open(fname2, newline='') as f2,\
     open(fname_out, 'w', newline='') as fout:

    reader1 = csv.reader(f1) 
    reader2 = csv.reader(f2)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)

    for row1, row2 in itertools.zip_longest(reader1, reader2, fillvalue=['0', '0', '0']):
        row_out = [int(a) + int(b) for a, b in zip(row1, row2)]
        writer.writerow(row_out)
```

The `itertools` implements the `zip_longest()`, that is similar to the built-in `zip()`; however, it can process the sequences of different lengths. Here the third parameter `fillvalue` is a quick hack -- 3 columns hardwired. Actually, it can be set to `[0, 0, 0]` (that is integers instead of strings) because `int(0)` is also zero.

Each `zip_longest()` extract a tuple of two rows -- the elements are assigned to `row1` and `row2`. Inside the loop, the normal `zip()` can be used as you will always have the row from the file or the `fillvalue` with zeros. You always get tupple with one element from the first row, and second element from the second row. They have to be converted from string to int and then they are added to form a single element in `row_out`.

A better solution of the loop, that does not rely on the fixed number of columns, uses the default `None` as the `fillvalue`. If one of the rows is `None`, then it is set to the list with the same number of zeros that has the other row. It means that you can even have rows of different length in the same file (but must be the same i both files; the opposite could also be solved easily using `zip_longest()` also in the body of the loop.

```
    for row1, row2 in itertools.zip_longest(reader1, reader2):

        if row1 is None:
            row1 = [0] * len(row2)
        elif row2 is None:    
            row2 = [0] * len(row1)

        row_out = [int(a) + int(b) for a, b in zip(row1, row2)]
        writer.writerow(row_out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

It can read CSV files and it can add two columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(filename_1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(filename_2)

df1['column_A'] += df2['column_*A*']
```